# How to decide the subject in this type of sentences?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> The number of guests invited to the wedding *is/are* one thousand.

How to decide the subject in this type of sentences?

Comment: You could say "The number of applications are primarily limited by our imagination." I cannot explain when the plural should be used instead of the singular, thought.

Comment: Take away all the adjectives, prepositions and reduce the sentence to its bare essence:  subject-verb.  Then it should be clear whether the subject is singular or plural.  The number is ...

Comment: In short, "the number of guests […] is one thousand" is what normally you should write. I cannot explain if "the number of applications are […]" is a common error or something that is acceptable because a specific reason.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Although there are a dozen instances of ["The number of applications **are** limited"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22The+number+of+applications+are+limited%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books, most of them are in constructions like *"The cost, **and** the number of..."*. The few that aren't like that are just plain incorrect, but there are several hundred instances of ["The number of applications **is** limited"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22The+number+of+applications+is+limited%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which is what I'd have expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this exact construction, the only rationale choice is singular **is**. As @Jim comments, just pare it down...

> "The number of guests invited to the wedding is one thousand."
>    "Can you repeat that please?"
>    "The number of guests is one thousand."
>    "I still didn't hear you. Once again, please?"
>    "**The number is** one thousand."

---

Note: although *"**the** number [of whatever]"* invariably takes a *singular* verb form, *"**a** number [of whatever]"* normally takes the *plural* verb form...

> **A number** of guests **are** planning to skip the actual ceremony and go straight to the reception party.

Comment: I might be misreading, but I think the source of OP's confusion is: "Is *number* the subject of the sentence, or is *guests*?" I know the answer, but can't think of how to explain the rationale. /puzzles

Comment: @WendiKidd♦: I thought the best way to get that across was to follow Jim's advice and shave away the grammatically irrelevant words (which includes **of guests**).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I found one good article. Look at Rule 10 http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp. *The expression **the number** is followed by a singular verb*.

Comment: @Sudhir: As a native speaker, I wasn't immediately aware of *why* learners might have a problem with this usage. But your link, plus a bit more thought on my part, prompts me to extend my answer to address ***a number** [of whatever]* - which is invariably followed by a *plural* verb.